# Change version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I accidentally changed my rails version to 4.0.0. I've tried gem uninstall rails --version=4.0.0.rc1 and install version 3.2.13 but when rails -v it's still version 4.0.0. I then tried gem uninstall rails, which gives me "Successfully uninstalled rails-3.2.13". Thought this was easy to do, but I can't find a simple solution.

Comment: Here you have a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179576/how-do-i-switch-to-older-versions-of-the-ruby-rails-environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **this:**

```
rvm use <ruby version>
```

You can also check your installed ruby versions using `rvm list` and then switch over. Then do:

```
rvm gemset create rails3.2.13
rvm <ruby version>@rails3.2.13
gem install rails --version=3.2.13
```

Comment: rvm gemset use <ruby version>@rails3.2.13

Answer (score -1):

Remove your `Gemfile.lock` and install rails again. Make sure you specify the version of Rails.

```
source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails',           '3.2.13'
```