# rails -v keeps saying Rails 3.2.13 after installing 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

What gives?

I typed this in `gem install rails -v 4.2.2`

After that, I tried `rails -v`, and it keeps coming out Rails 3.2.13

Why is this?

My ruby version after `ruby -v`

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage gems with bundler (http://bundler.io/)

Put this on your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
```

> gem install bundler

and then

> bundle install
>
> bundle exec rails -v

If you still working without bundler, you can make

> gem list

look at your rails version and then uninstall older versions

> gem uninstall rails --version 3.2.13

and then

> rails -v

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before. And this is what I did. 
[Change version of rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315598/change-version-of-rails)
Just change the versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of Rails installed, you'll get conflicting information like this.

If you need to run a command with a specific version of Rails, you can specify the version as part of the command, eg.

```
rails _4.2.2_ -v
```

That will tell you you are using Rails 4.2.

Once you've created a new app by doing something like `rails _4.2.2_ new app_name`, then the Gemfile for that app will specify Rails 4.2.2 and you can drop the special prefix.